# Access an individual element of a Perl 2x2 array

Tags: perl

I am able to create a matrix using this code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

@arr1 = (10,20,30);
@arr2 = (10,20,30);
@arr3 = (10,20,30);
@ref_arr = (\@arr1, \@arr2, \@arr3);

print"Prog starts\n";          

foreach $ref (@ref_arr) {
  #print @$ref->[0];
  foreach $val (@$ref) { 
    print "$val ";
  }
  print"\n";
}
```

Using the `map` function I can modify each value in the matrix like this

Example: increase every value by 1

```
foreach $ref (@ref_arr) {
  map($_++, @$ref);
}
```

but I want to modify a certain row or a specific value, i.e. either add 1 to all of the second row's values or to the first column of the second row

Comment: Also, check out http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html for more good examples.

Comment: @ Thank u for link :) it's really a good one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* program that you write. This applies especially if you are asking for help with your code, as these measures will reveal simple errors that you would otherwise overlook

The `map` function is *not* for iterating over a list: it is for 'mapping' one list to another by applying a function to each element of the source list

When you write

```
map($_++,@$ref)
```

you are building and discarding a copy of the values in `@list`. What you should write is

```
$_++ for @$ref
```

As for how to modify a single value out of the array, your array initialisation can be simplified to

```
my @data = (
    [10, 20, 30], 
    [10, 20, 30], 
    [10, 20, 30]
)
```

I hope from this it is easier to see that the first `10` in the structure is accessible as `$data[0][0]` and, say, the last `20` is `$data[2][1]` (remembering that Perl arrays are indexed from zero). You can access and modifiy these values just as any ordinary scalar

As for your particular examples, the second row is `@{$data[1]}` so you can increment every element of the row by writing `$_++ for @{$data[1]}`. The first column of the second row is incremented with `$data[1][0]++`

Comment: "you are building and discarding" Is this still true? I have read that recent perls do not build the list in void context.

Comment: No. The internal functionality of `map` has been modified so that it doesn't uselessly build and discard an array where it has been called in void context. But the call is still asking for that to be done, and it is wrong to rely on Perl's benevolence. Indeed, proper use of `map` should have *no* side-effects at all - i.e. the block should change nothing and do no IO: it should just return a (list) value

Answer (score 3):

Are you using `row x column` or `column x row`? I will assume the first.

To modify the value at `$x, $y`:

```
$ref_arr[$x][$y] = $new_value;
```

To add 1 to column `$x`:

```
$_++ for @{ $ref_arr[$x] };
```

To add 1 to row `$y`:

```
$_->[$y]++ for @ref_arr;
```